# Forcing text into a document with class

Tags: templates, preamble

I'm creating a style sheet for my organizations memos and reports.  I need to include a disclaimer type of statement into ever report created with the style.  I'm uses a class document (*.cls) based off of the basic article class.  Is there a way to force a statement to appear in every report?  I do not want it on every page just at the beginning or end of every document, preferably at the end.

Comment: In your class file, use `\AtBeginDocument{...}`.

Comment: @jubobs -- i think you mean `\AtEndDocument{...}`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The OP writes "at the beginning or end of every document", so both macros would be useful, I guess.

Comment: Do you want it to appear on every pdf you create or in the log  file during compilation?

Comment: AFAIK, `\AtBeginDocument{...}` is *not* intended for typeset material. From the LaTeX Companion, 2.ed.: "Note, however, that code in the `\AtBeginDocument` hook is part of the preamble. Thus, restrictions limit what can be put there; in particular, no typesetting can be done."

Comment: The \AtEndDocument appears to be working however there is a problematic interaction with the background package, so that it is forced onto it's own page.

Comment: Why not define a new page style `info`to insert some info on footer or header? Then you can use `\thispagestyle{info}`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I must have been thinking about `etoolbox`'s `\AfterEndPreamble`.

Comment: Could you put it into a one time header?  Also check out the flowfram package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This trial sets a statement (well current time, date, total number of pages and file name) to the footer of the first page and some similar content for the last page using the `etoolbox` command `AfterPreamble` and the standard LaTeX hook `\AtEndDocument`.

I found, that it should be possible to print statements to appear right on the first page with `\AtBeginDocument` as well.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox} %important for \AfterPreamble
% Eye candy and other commands, only relevant to what
% should be written at begin / end of document.
\usepackage{datetime}%
\usepackage{blindtext}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{scrpage2}%

\newcounter{TotalPageNumber}%

\newrobustcmd{\WriteBeginDocumentStatement}[1][]{%
\noindent\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{This document with \theTotalPageNumber~page(s) named "\jobname.tex" was generated at
  \currenttime~ on \today} #1}\par
}

\newrobustcmd{\WriteEndDocumentStatement}{%
\noindent\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{End of  "\jobname.tex" at
  \currenttime~ on \today}}\par
}


\AfterPreamble{%
\cfoot{%
\ifnumless{\number\value{page}}{2}{% Only on first page!
\parbox{0.8\textwidth}{%
\WriteBeginDocumentStatement[ -- inserted from \texttt{\(\backslash\)AfterPreamble}]
}}{%
% nothing else
}}
}%

\AtBeginDocument{%
\WriteBeginDocumentStatement[ -- inserted from \texttt{\(\backslash\)AtBeginDocument}]%
}%

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
\cfoot{%
\WriteEndDocumentStatement}%
\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\setcounter{TotalPageNumber}{\number\value{page}}}
}% 
\makeatother

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\newpage
\blindtext[8]
\newpage
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note: the screenshot is cropped!**